# Setting that limits downloaded file size for Firefox profile?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm setting up my firefox profile as such:

```
        firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

        ff_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        ff_profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
        ff_profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
        ff_profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', self.download_dir)
        ff_profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/zip')
        ff_profile.set_preference('app.update.auto', False)
        ff_profile.set_preference('app.update.enabled', False)
        ff_profile.set_preference('webgl.disabled', True)
        ff_profile.set_preference('webdriver.log.file', getenv('PWD') + '/firefox_webdriver.log')
        ff_profile.set_preference('webdriver.firefox.logfile', getenv('PWD') + '/firefox_browser.log')

        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ff_profile,
                                   capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
```

When I use the driver to download a file below some certain size, all is well.  above that certain size, the test will subsequently fail to find the downloaded file because Firefox has presented a dialog with the following content:

```
You have chosen to open: [the file name] 
which is: Binary File 
from: [the source location].  
Would you like to save this file?
```

If I step through the test with the debugger, and manually accept this dialog, all is well.  The different thing about this particular file is that it is 6MB.  Other files that download successfully are much smaller, less than 1MB.  This suggests that there is a certain file size that Firefox is deciding is too big to download without approval, in spite of my profile settings.

I have searched through the settings in Firefox's about:config, but I did not find any that would seem to address this problem.

Are you aware of any additional preference I can set in my profile that would allow me to increase this file size limit?  Is there some other way to address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, someone pointed out to me that the distinction was not size, but file type.  All I needed to do was accommodate the additional file type in my preferences:

```
   ff_profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',
                             'application/zip, attachment/csv, application/octet-stream')
```